# Python - How to get through PermissionError in Windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, file-permissions

So i wrote a simple script to manage startup by separating it into different setups

I then wrote a simple install script that is just supposed to create directories

They both worked just fine on MacOS and Linux when i tested them

but when I tried to run them on Windows I got a PermissionError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\install.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open(yml_file_dir+file_sep+'conf.yml', 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\kerem\\AppData\\Local\\Kerem Göksu\\Startups\\0.1.0-alpha\\conf.yml'
```

install script:

```
import os, platform
from appdirs import AppDirs

dirs = AppDirs("Startups", "Kerem Göksu", version="0.1.0-alpha")
file_sep = "\\" if platform.system() == "Windows" else "/"
yml_file_dir = dirs.user_data_dir

try: os.makedirs(yml_file_dir)
except FileExistsError: pass

with open(yml_file_dir+file_sep+'conf.yml', 'w') as f:
    f.write("""startup_prompt: 'What startup will you use today? '
startups:
  hello:
  - echo Hello, World!""")
```

So how can I get permission in Windows? There is no sudo in Windows.
Or is there a way I could do this without needing to get permission?

I am running Windows 7 Version 6.1 Build Number 7601, SP1

Comment: *There is no `sudo` in Windows.* True, but there is a near-equivalent. It's called *Run as Administrator*. The `appdata` folder may have restricted permissions.

Comment: Use `os.path.join` instead of string concatenation. For elevation prompt use `ShellExecute` via *pywin32* or *ctypes*